# How to disable all Shiny UI elements, including a downloadButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851729/how-can-i-disable-all-action-buttons-while-shiny-is-busy-and-loading-text-is-dis) explains how can one disable/enable all UI elements in a Shiny app.

Among the two solutions given, the one I am interested in uses the shinyjs package (I'd rather not play with javascript directly).

My problem is that UI elements of the class downloadButton are not listed as elements of input.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tagList(
        downloadButton("downloadBtn", "Download button"),
        actionButton("printBtn", "Print and disable all members of input")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$printBtn, { 
        
        print (names(input))
        for(n in names(input))
            shinyjs::disable(id=n)
        
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I click on  the "Print all members of input", only "printBtn" is printed ("downloadBtn" is not).

Hence, since downloadButton is not a member of input, disabling it by looping over all the elements of input - and disabling them one by one does not work.

Is there an elegant workaround that can be used in order to disable all of the elements?

Comment: can you show the shinyjs code you tried to use? are you saying `shinyjs::disable("downloadBtn")` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: `downloadButton` seems to be handled differently to `actionButton`.  The first clue is in the name of its first parameter: `outputId` rather than `inputId`.  I can't tell you why.   In your example, `output_downloadBtn_hidden` is an element of `session$clientData`.  (Add `session` to your server function definition.)

Comment: @Mike I have added the shinyjs code. The part which does not work is `for(n in names(input)) shinyjs::disable(id=n) `.  It does not disable the `downloadBtn` as wanted. I gave a simplified code example - in reality, I want to disable a downloadButton from inside a module. If it were a member of `input`, I would pass `input` to the module as a variable, and then loop over it  - disabling all its elements. However, since downloadButton is not a member of input, this solution does not work.